# SQL Server 2005 - TSQL For Xml query to get grouped departments and employees

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, nested, for-xml

For a database holding 3 tables:

1. Company
2. Department
3. EmployeeInDepartment

I would like to a xml like below:

```
<Companies>
  <Company>
    <CompanyName></CompanyName>
    <CompanyId></CompanyId>
    <..></..>
    <Departments>
       <Name></Name>
       <..></..>
       <Employees>
          <Employee>
             <FirstName></FirstName>
             <LastName></LastName>
             .. .. ..
          </Employee>
          .. .. ..
       </Employees>
    </Departments>
    .. .. ..
  </Company>
  .. .. .. 
</Companies>
```

Where the company is repeating (tags), departments inside company are repeating (tags) and Employee inside departments are repeating (tags) by repeating I mean there are more than one number of these element & not the data.

**Relations**

1. `Company` and `Department` are related through **`FK`** in `Department` table that links to `CompanyId` in `Company` table.
2. `Department` and `EmployeeInDepartment` are related through 'FK' in `EmployeeInDepartment` table that links to `DepartmentId` in `Department` table.

#### Query:

execute the below on PUBS database and check the xml, it will have more than one Jobs with id 10

```
select jobs.job_id 'JobId',
job_desc 'Desc',
(
    select emp_id 'EmployeeId',fname 'FirstName',lname 'LastName' from employee where job_id = jobs.job_id for xml path('Emploees'),type
)
from jobs
inner join 
employee on  jobs.job_id = employee.job_id
for xml path('employees')
```

Comment: You should use `for xml path` and I think you will find all you need [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) and in these [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Hi mikael, yes i am using `for xml path` mode just that the departments for the company are not in order( 3 first records for companyid = 1, next with company id 2, next again with company id 1) so when i run the query i get 2 company tags with same company id.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the query you have.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson sure i can . sorry that that diagram would aid more in the process.

Comment: Your query and a description of issues you have would turn this into a question. Now it looks more like "can someone please do this for me" :).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson i am sorry i made you feel so, was travelling back home from work so couldn't post the code. Could you check the query now and tell why the multiple id appear

Comment: No worries. I have added a sample with table variables (don't have pubs). Your issue is that you join the tables in every part of the query. The sub.queries should be correlated to the outer queries so you only get the rows you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do "nested" `FOR XML` statements - that should give you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
   (some 'Company' columns),
   (SELECT
       (some 'Department' columns),
       (SELECT
           (some 'Employee' columns),
        FROM dbo.EmployeeInDepartment e
        WHERE e.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
        FOR XML PATH('Employee'), TYPE
       ) AS 'Employees'
    FROM dbo.Department d
    WHERE d.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
    FOR XML PATH('Department'), TYPE
   ) AS 'Departments'
FROM dbo.Company c
FOR XML PATH('Company'), ROOT('Companies')
```

See e.g. Richard Dingwall's [Nested FOR XML results with SQL Server](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/26/nested-xml-results-from-sql-server-with-for-xml-path/) that shows how to do this. Of course, you can easily nest more than two levels...

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure how you want this but this should give you a start.

```
declare @jobs table
(
  job_id int,
  job_desc varchar(10)
)

declare @employee table
(
  emp_id int,
  fname varchar(10),
  lname varchar(10),
  job_id int
)

insert into @jobs values
(1, 'Job 1'),
(2, 'Job 2')

insert into @employee values
(1, 'first 1', 'last 1', 1),
(2, 'first 2', 'last 2', 1),
(3, 'first 3', 'last 3', 2)

select employee.emp_id 'EmployeeId',
       employee.fname 'FirstName',
       employee.lname 'LastName',
       (
        select jobs.job_id 'JobId',
               jobs.job_desc 'Desc'
        from @jobs jobs
        where jobs.job_id = employee.emp_id
        for xml path('jobs'),type        
       )
from @employee employee
for xml path('employees')
```

Result:

```
<employees>
  <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
  <FirstName>first 1</FirstName>
  <LastName>last 1</LastName>
  <jobs>
    <JobId>1</JobId>
    <Desc>Job 1</Desc>
  </jobs>
</employees>
<employees>
  <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
  <FirstName>first 2</FirstName>
  <LastName>last 2</LastName>
  <jobs>
    <JobId>2</JobId>
    <Desc>Job 2</Desc>
  </jobs>
</employees>
<employees>
  <EmployeeId>3</EmployeeId>
  <FirstName>first 3</FirstName>
  <LastName>last 3</LastName>
</employees>
```

You should not join all your tables in every part. The main query only queries the information that is needed for the root level and the sub-queries only query the information needed there with a where clause `where jobs.job_id = employee.emp_id` that filters the rows in the sub queries so you only get the rows you want in the child nodes.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me.`select jobs.job_id 'JobId',
job_desc 'Desc',
(
 select emp_id 'EmployeeId',fname 'FirstName',lname 'LastName' from employee where job_id = jobs.job_id for xml path('Employee'),type
) 'Employees'
from jobs
for xml path('employees')`